# How to write by column rather than rows - Python to CSV

Tags: python, export-to-csv

I want to write my python list `all_results` to CSV. However when I use the following code, it saves each individual record in rows rather than columns.

```
import csv
fh = open('output.csv', 'w')
cvs_writer = csv.writer(fh)

# write one row with headers (using `writerow` without `s` at the end)
cvs_writer.writerow(["Column 1"])

# write many rows with results (using `writerows` with `s` at the end)
cvs_writer.writerows([all_results])
                                                                                            
fh.close()
```

Output

```
|Column 1|
|row 1| |row 2| |row 3| |row 4| |row 5| |row 6| ---
```

Expected Output

```
|Column 1|
|row 1|
|row 2|
|row 3|
|row 4|
|row 5|
|row 6|
```

Comment: What output do you expect?

Comment: WHAT IF THERE ARE TWO COLUMNS `column 1` and `column 2`